# Prolog - unexpected end of file

Tags: input, io, prolog

## Reading a file in Prolog error

Hi, I'm working on a Prolog project and I need to read the whole file in it. I have a file named 'meno.txt' and I need to read it. I found some code here on stack. The code is following:

```
main :-
  open('meno.txt', read, Str),
  read_file(Str,Lines),
  close(Str),
  write(Lines), nl.


read_file(Stream,[]) :-
    at_end_of_stream(Stream).


read_file(Stream,[X|L]) :-
    \+ at_end_of_stream(Stream),
    read(Stream,X),
    read_file(Stream,L).
```

When I call the `main/0` predicate, I get an error saying unexpected end of file. My file looks like this:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

I also found the similar problem here and the solution where in ASCII and UTF coding but I tried that and it seems its not my solution. Can anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How read a file and write another file in prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855982/how-read-a-file-and-write-another-file-in-prolog)

Comment: If each of the line is a predicate, such as `subtype("apple","fruit")`, and the input file were written by Prolog I/O originally, my question is, how do you write to file with a period at the end in the first place?

Answer (score 7):

The predicate `read/2` reads Prolog terms from a file. Those must end with a period. Try updating the contents of your file to:

```
line1.
line2.
line3.
line4.
```

The unexpected end of file you're getting likely results from the Prolog parser trying to find an ending period.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using SWI Prolog, you may use something like this for the read:

```
read_file(Stream,[X|L]) :-
    \+ at_end_of_stream(Stream),
    read_line_to_codes(Stream,Codes),
    atom_chars(X, Codes),
    read_file(Stream,L), !.
```

`read_line_to_codes/2` reads each line directly into an array of character codes. Then `atom_chars/2` will convert the codes to an atom.